# Like "make" for Docker

Tags: python, bash, docker, makefile

I am working add wrapping my application in a docker container, which leads my to type some pretty verbose commands pretty often:

```
sudo docker build -t foo/bar .
sudo docker run foo/bar /bin/bash /path/to/my/script/test_report.sh
...
```

I want some way to wrap these in a script, making them easier to execute, and letting me forget the details between runs.

Make does this pretty well. Instructions can be wrapped together, so I can do `make test`, `make run`, `make deploy` or whatever.

I suppose there is nothing stopping me from just using make, but is there a more modern solution, that doesn't break when I use spaces instead of tabs and is just more pleasant to work with?

My project is Python, but I am looking for a generic solution. Preferably one that lets me wrap bash scripts (since that allows me infinite flexibility)

Comment: If you just want to wrap some bash commands, why don't you write a bash script (with subcommands if you prefer)??? Or a file with function definitions which you can source and execute the functions? (That's not "modern" in any sense — must be as old as bash itself.)

Comment: Hmm... well, that might be the most intuitive way of doing it... And I guess it doesn't add any boilerplate... Just some if-else to match the arguments.

Comment: There are only approximately *inifinite* make replacements. In virtually every language you can think of. Whether they are "better" or not depends on what you need to do with them and whether they support that or not. A quick search should find many of them. That said a script is usually a reasonable start as well, especially if you don't have "avoid rebuilding" concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at docker-compose.

If you create the following *docker-compose.yml* file in the same folder as your *Dockerfile*:

```
foobar:
    build: .
    command: /bin/bash /path/to/my/script/test_report.sh
```

you can then build with: `docker-compose build`

and start a new container with :`docker-compose up`

---

What's interesting with Docker compose is that you can define in the compose file anything related to the *docker run* command such as volumes, published ports, etc.

For more info take a look at the Docker compose [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) and [file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).

Answer (score 0):

[dobi](https://dnephin.github.io/dobi/) is designed to be exactly that tool. A "build automation" tool that uses containers for all the tasks. Everything is configured in a yaml file, and you can run tasks like you would with `make`:  `dobi <task>`